# Create index WITH (ONLINE = ON) using SSDT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

Can I create indexes with ONLINE option set to ON using SSDT publish? If I add such definition to the index publish is simply ignoring that setting. SQL Server 2017 Enterprise

Comment: Just a wild guess, but is the package configured to be deployed to an Enterprise edition server, and are you in fact deploying to an Enterprise edition server? Online index operations are only supported there (though typically SSDT should give an error, not silently scrap such things).

Comment: We use Enterprise

Comment: Perhaps worthy of an answer @MartinSmith?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annoyingly SSDT ignores this property.

If you are on a version of SQL Server that supports the `ELEVATE_ONLINE` [database scoped configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you can use this to ensure that all such operations happen online (SQL Server 2017 Enterprise is not such an edition, currently this is a preview option in Azure only).

Alternatively you can set your deployment pipeline up to run a ["pre model" phase](https://sabin.io/blog/ssdt-and-pre-model-scripts/) that can include custom scripts to create the index if needed with desired options before the SSDT diff is generated.

To achieve this entirely within SSDT you would need to use a deploy contributor. For this option an example project you may well find highly relevant is [EditionAwareCreateIndex](https://github.com/DacFxDeploymentContributors/Contributors/tree/master/src/EditionAwareCreateIndex)

Comment: Yeah, normally if you need something then first check Eddie's blog :)

Comment: @Martin - do you know if this has changed at all since 2019?

Comment: @HannahVernon - I don't know. I've just got used to using pre-model scripts. I kind of suspect that it won't have changed though as it has been a long standing problem and enhancements to SSDT seem to only be around keeping pace with new language features

Comment: It's too bad - seems to me that Enterprise Edition licensees are the folks most likely to have their T-SQL in source control.  Specifically, I am trying to retrofit an existing sprawling system into git control and want to enable `DATA_COMPRESSION = ON` without having to change all the index definitions in my VS project, and then write a script to change almost all 1,200 indexes.  Seems silly that the project file doesn't have an option for targeting the SQL Server Edition.  I'll head over to Connect, no UserVoice, no Docs and complain to the void I suppose lol.